# Should I be concerned for Viruses when I download through Steam?

Tags: steam, earthlock

While I was downloading *[Earthlock: Festival of Magic](http://store.steampowered.com/app/258030/EARTHLOCK_Festival_of_Magic/)* AVG popped up:

[image: AVG Virus]

I suspended the download of this game until I could confirm if the game is safe.

I know that sometimes Anti-Virus might give false positives when an innocent file does something similar to a known Virus, but when it comes to PC safety, I can't always give the benefit of the doubt.

I am wondering however, should I be concerned for Viruses when I download through Steam? Or is this just a known false positive and downloading through Steam is actually safe?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the game, but given the context: Have you played the game before on that machine, or different machine but same steam profile, do you have any mods or Plugins (Community or not) installed for that game now or previously ?

Comment: @ИвоНедев i bought the game like last week i think. this is the first time i am downloading it and the AVG Noticed appeared as it was downloading and so far no other game has done this (though there are a bunch og games i haven't downloaded yet)

Comment: AVG is full of false positives. Honestly, anything more than MS Defender is unnecessary, unless you're always downloading suspicious content from suspicious sources.

Comment: @Chippies ... and if you're always downloading suspicious content from suspicious sources, there's no anti-virus that can protect you.

Comment: Getting a game onto Steam is quite hard. And Valve requires lots of paperwork from developers. That makes it even harder to do it while not revealing your identity. I doubt any game developer would risk to get blacklisted by Valve because they bundled their game with malware.

Comment: From all of the speculation happening in the comments about a purported Steam game file validation and virus scan process, but with no real direct experience or knowledge, @Philipp's comment seems the best to think on.

Comment: Last but not least, I'd expect a thread about this on their Steam's discussion board, or worse, a negative review about virus detection. **Edit**: apparently, there's none.

Comment: @Chippies Very false. Windows Defender has the worst detection rate of any antivirus on the market (70% vs most of them 95%). It's like saying you don't need Chrome or Firefox because you already have Edge.

Comment: @JopV. It's more like saying you don't need Firefox because you already have `telnet` - ignoring the BSODs, the UI... the Edge engine is pretty much equivalent - at time of writing it's the IE14 engine.

Comment: @JopV. I don't know where you got your numbers, but according to [AV-Test.org](https://www.av-test.org/en/antivirus/home-windows/windows-10/october-2016/microsoft-windows-defender-4.10-164047/) MS Defender detects 88'ish % of 0-day and close to 100% of threats discovered in last 4 weeks. That combined with the fact that it's very lightweight, has hardly any false positives and won't annoy me in general (i.e most of the time I don't even know I have it enabled), with a little bit of common sense makes it the best AV **for me**.

Comment: @Chippies: Honestly I would even say any AV whatsoever in the first place is probably unnecessary for the computer-savvy, but I'm sure people will disagree...

Comment: It flagged a .dll file as evil. How is AVG supposed to know that this is malicious or not? Very likely a false alarm

Answer (score 73):

win32.BogEnt is a known false positive for digital download games. It should be fine to play this. win32.BogEnt is a heuristic-based indicator. This is not based on the scanned file being known to the software as a virus, but rather the software doing some analysis on the file and deciding that it MIGHT be a virus based on stuff like it sharing certain code fragments with a virus, or it might use rarely used instructions, or it might be run in a contained sandbox environment to see what it does. Heuristics frequently give false positives.

The overwhelming majority of games on Steam are pretty safe to download, especially if they're already on there for a couple of months. However, some games get bundled with invasive DRM, although that's not really a virus.

Comment: +1. Steam isn't allowing any old file to just go into their system, you'd have to imagine they're checking things for safety first. They'd be a dead platform if they didn't!

Comment: It would be good to see a reputable source for the "known false positive" part of this answer. The paranoid part of my brain says "that's exactly what an attacker would want you to believe", and "some random person on the internet says it's safe" would be a poor reason to trust something.

Comment: I had a similar false positive when downloading some mods from the Steam Workshop, but I feel that isn't as well vetted as the actual Steam games

Comment: @IMSoP I have added a number of links to games that have been reported by Avast as suspicious.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Steam makes no guarantees that the games they distribute are virus-free, secure, or even not actively harmful. It's simply infeasible to check every update that goes out for every game.  See section 7.C of the subscriber agreement: http://store.steampowered.com/subscriber_agreement/

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Publishers routinely dump their entire inventory of games on Steam when they have the ability to do so. It is/was not uncommon to have 50% of the "new games" on Steam be uploads from games published in the 90's. Some of them do not work, some of them handle so horribly that it is weird someone would be even asking any money for it. The thing is, Steam is a digital marketplace. They have unlimited* space. Having these lists of old games doesn't hurt them (enough) to actively curate these backlists.

Comment: If Steam were such an open platform from such blase developers, the platform would have crashed and burned years ago. There's obviously something going on behind the scenes to prevent virus infections or the like, otherwise we'd all have been burned by now.

Comment: "Some games get bundled with invasive DRM" -- yeah, it's called "Steam"

Comment: @AC this is off-topic, but Steam is one of the least invasive forms of DRM on the PC gaming market. There's some games that don't even have DRM on Steam (yes, they don't even require steam to be running).

Comment: I would like to point out that while invasive DRM may not officially be considered a virus, it can oftentimes be just as bad as one.  StarForce, for example, has been known to cause physical damage to CD-ROM drives due to bad programming, likes to disable SCSI devices because it assumes they're all virtual drives for mounting images (considering that [Windows has a tendency to detect SATA drives (such as, say, an HDD) as SCSI devices](http://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=1433), this is a **_VERY BAD IDEA_**), and creates an enormous security hole.

Comment: @JvR Understood. I removed the references to Avast from the question. It still remains that it's a heuristic indicator, which is less cut and dry compared to the older fingerprinting methods.

Comment: @JustinTime More recently, I remember when Street Fighter V installed a literal rootkit on users' PCs in an attempt to stop cheaters. Thankfully that change was rolled back since then.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I think your level of trust in Valve and Steam is unwarranted and potentially hazardous to your (computer’s) health. For a long time *Steam itself* was considered by some (myself included) to be malware, because it was a buggy, system-stability-degrading piece of crap that was almost impossible to remove. It has grown an *awful lot* since then (I use it myself), but Valve is neither perfect nor necessarily always in your best interest.

Comment: @JustinTime DRM may not qualify as a virus, as it doesnt generally replicate. But it definitely does count as malware. "Software which is specifically designed to disrupt, damage or ... a computer system." DRM's entire purpose is to disrupt someone performing certain activities with their computer. (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/malware)

Comment: @Kaizerwolf "If Steam were such an open platform from such blase developers, the platform would have crashed and burned years ago"—that's completely unfounded statement. Sh**ty platforms from blase developers have proven to be wildly successful over the course of recent decades (see Google Play etc) Furthermore, there is absolutely nothing they can do to curate games except promptly removing them, when someone reports presence of actual virus. As demonstrated by the question, the virus scanners are ineffective in detecting things and would damage Valve's busyness, if they were relying on those

Comment: …(continued) as such, the only detergent from publishing viruses in Steam is the breadth of bureaucratic procedures, required to do so. If the virus maker is required to register themselves, even just as small business, remaining unpunished would be a lot harder for them, reducing their motivation. But there is nothing, stopping viruses from infecting computers of game developers and injecting malware into game binaries before those are published. There is no magical wand, that could stop that from happening. Not in Steam, not in Apple Store, not anywhere else.

Comment: @user1643723 There's a distinction, Kaizerwolf is referring to the fact that steam probably does have antivirus behind the scenes to prevent bad apps from going on. You're also right that there is no magic bullet, and thus steam provides no guarantees. But that doesn't mean that the only thing stopping malware is the bureaucracy. Likewise, Google Play also has various security scanners to protect the users. Virus scanners are ineffective at detecting _all_, but they are very effective at detecting _most_.

Comment: @MooingDuck sure, antivirus software does good job at raising entry barrier for malware making. But it is largely ineffective as means of 0-day protection. It is a good thing, that Google Play etc. scan everything with those scanners, but for completely different reasons, not because of 0-day protection they (don't) offer. To put it simply… law enforcement does largely decent job protecting society as whole against robbery, but that does not mean, that you can stay calm, when someone points a knife at you on a dark street. Users themselves still should employ discretion.

Comment: @Kryan First off, I'm not an idiot that relies on the company to protect me; I've had my share of viruses in the past, so I take care of my computer. Secondly, to user1643723, this isn't the place to talk about this, nor should you be so prickly about the whole situation. Attacking me and my words isn't really the best way to approach this.

Answer (score 14):

I suppose you can never be too safe, but you shouldn't really be concerned for viruses on Steam.
[susp] in the virus' name stands for "suspicious", which means the anti-virus itself isn't sure if it's even a threat or not. Games downloaded on Steam are (supposed to be) virus-free.

Comment: Games distributed in retail boxes via CD & DVD "are (supposed to be) virus-free" too.  That plan didn't always come together....

Comment: Games on Steam can be managed better. If a game in a retail box has a virus, there's nothing that can be done besides a recall (and who's gonna do that, really), whereas on Steam if a malicious developer did decide to go rogue and distribute a virus with their game, it would get caught quickly and they would lose pretty much everything, starting with their game getting pulled from the store, and their reputation destroyed.
I'd be iffy with indie devs publishing a game that looks like it took them couple hours to make and no reputation to lose, but in this case there's definitely money to lose

Comment: Bad actors gave us root-kit-as-DRM in retail boxes.  Viruses in retail boxes were almost always the result of oversight & carelessness. Steam can help greatly here, but it's no magic bullet.

Comment: Which is why I said "supposed to be" :P It's not guaranteed, but the chances are extremely slim. In this case - even the AV isn't sure if it's a threat, but warned the user anyway.

Answer (score 6):

I'm fairly sure that's a false positive, if I'm not mistaken it's the dll for [Gog's Galaxy client](https://www.gog.com/galaxy).

Earthlock is available on Gog and has Galaxy support so it's reasonable to assume that's what it is. The Steam.dll gets included in quite a lot of Gog's DRM free games too so I imagine the developers just use the same builds for both in many cases.

As has already been mentioned many games and game clients get flagged as viruses or malware by over enthusiastic anti virus.

Answer (score 0):

There are many files that act in ways that certain antivirus programs see as problematic. For me personally, I had an issue with Sid Meier's Civilization V where the .exe would get quarantined by Symantec.

Steam is usually pretty good with keeping viruses from getting into their downloads and keeping them out of their network. I'd say not to expect any viruses from a Steam download.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to remember about Steam is that it has a very large user base. That equates to a very large number of people available to report 'this game has a virus'. It's true that there are other factors that affect this (the virus may only target certain users, people might not report the virus, the game may not have been bought by many people etc) but on the whole, if there's a lot of satisfied customers then it seems likely that these people have not experienced viruses and thus unlikely that the game does contain a virus.

That said, there are some games with 3rd party anti-cheat systems that are somewhat invasive and questionable (I remember one game in particular used an anti-cheat system that required a Windows service to be installed).

Answer (score -4):

The original question was "Should I be concerned for Viruses when I download through Steam?"

I believe the correct answer is to ALWAYS be concerned when downloading ANY software from ANY source. Always assume the download could contain a virus (whether intentional or not).

Now, that being said... Steam is a very popular platform for a large community of gamers and I am certain they would do as much as they can to properly vet new games and their developers. But there's only so much they can do and, ultimately, the responsibility of securing your machine is yours alone. When something suspicious pops up, it's your duty to research it before allowing it onto your machine.

You've done the right thing. You've asked for help. You can also Google the "virus" that is flagged and see what it might be. Just be aware that because something SAYS it is one thing, doesn't mean it actually is. A flag that turns out to be a "false positive" on your search could actually be a true virus that is just named after what is now commonly assumed to be a false positive.

Crafty little buggers, aren't they?

Comment: If you search for the false positive in reference to a specific game though you can see if that particular one is a false positive  (unless the devs were extremely shady and replaced a false positive file with a real virus of the same name).

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be the devs of the game. How many games use 3rd party "anti-cheat" programs that could be compromised without the game devs even being involved or aware of the problem? One should never make assumptions that software is "safe." Always have anti-virus software in place to flag suspect programs before they can do damage. When unsure, look deeper and make an educated guess as to whether you can trust it.